# Disallow merging into a different branch than you branched from?

Tags: git, merge, branch

We have our repo configured in the following way:

```
master
--> project_branch
----> branch_of_project_branch
--> branch_of_master
```

IE, we have a bunch of projects that are all branches from a master branch.

When we make changes to master, we do those changes in a branch off of master, and then merge them back into master, then pull from master into each project branch.

When we make changes to a project, we do those changes in a branch off of that project, and then merge them back into that project branch.

Is there any way to configure git so that we disallow merging changes from a branch into a branch that was not it's origin? IE, in the above example, I would want to forbid `branch_of_project_branch` from being merged into `master`, or likewise, forbid `branch_of_master` from being merged into `project_branch`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way to configure git so that we disallow merging changes from a branch into a branch that was not it's origin?

No.

Branch names in Git have no meaning and have no relationship to each other.  Each Git repository has *its own* branch names: if I clone your repository, I can change mine to have branches `maestro` instead of `master`, `dervish` instead of `develop`, and so on.  And yet, I can still send your Git commits, and tell your Git to use either your names, or my names.

Each branch name you have in your own Git repository *does* allow you to set one other name, which Git calls an *upstream*, to associate with that branch, but this upstream setting is local and is mainly a convenience feature.  Other parts of Git—such as the default setting of `push.default`—then encourage people to use `origin/master` as the upstream of a branch whose local name is `master`, thus *encouraging* a sensible use of branch names, but it's not enforced anywhere: anyone can override any of this at any time.

In any case, branch names are insignificant.  What matters in Git are the *commits*.  A branch name merely serves to *find* a commit.

When you have a server that hosts a Git repository, that *server* gets to accept or reject `git push` operations.  You can write your own scripts that check incoming push requests.  These scripts take the form of *hooks*, in this case, `pre-receive` and `update`.  But these hooks only get a few pieces of information:

- the hash ID of an incoming commit;
- the name the other Git asked your Git to use; and
- the hash ID currently associated with that name.

The person doing the `git push` operation can pick an arbitrary name to send to your Git, to ask your Git to use, so the branch name you see here is not necessarily the branch name *they* have in *their* Git.  But you need not *care* what branch name they have in their Git: your Git never sees *their* branch names anyway.  Your Git sees only your own branch names, and commit hashes.

The bottom line is this:  **Commit hashes are shared across all Git repositories.  Branch names are not.**  At the same time: **Each user's Git repositories are private that user.  You cannot control what anyone else does with their private Git repository.**  You can only control what you do with yours.

Comment: Thank you for the very thorough explanation. Wish it wasn't the case, but I suppose we'll just have to be extra-careful about which branch we commit to.